# WCF get Group of a User

Tags: c#, wcf

I wrote a huge application which uses WCF services to do things like read from databases and also to be able to use integrated security.

Atm I use the following code to get the current logged on user name:

```
string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

However I want to be able to get the active directory groups the user is in, because this would make it a lot easier instead of always adding new users. Anyone know how to do this in a clean and simple way?

Don't know if this is relevant, but my endpoint is configured as:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ZNA.Integratie.KopMon.Web.LoginServiceBehavior"
name="ZNA.Integratie.KopMon.Web.LoginService">
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Security" contract="ZNA.Integratie.KopMon.Web.LoginService" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

```
<behavior name="ZNA.Integratie.KopMon.Web.LoginServiceBehavior">
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
</behavior>

<binding name="Security">
  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

Comment: Why do you need the groups of which the user is a member? If it's for authorization purposes, a better model is simply to ask whether he or she is a member of a particular group/role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool hasAccess = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrators");
```

Comment: Aaah, a clean and simple answer. Always nice to read :)
Sorry for not figuring this out on my own